# Swf banner button hyperlinks don't work when there is NO "WWW" vs. with "WWW" in the URL?

Tags: xml, actionscript, hyperlink, flash

We have a swf banner with buttons/links on our site header.

When our customers DO NOT enter the "www" before our URL

the banner links do not work - do not forward to the page.

When our customers enter the "www" in the URL

It works.

First Thoughts,

Is it a security setting in the browsers? I tried the latest version of firefox, chrome, IE, safari, opera.

The links on the banner itself point to subdomains.

Here is a sample action script for the one of the links:

on (release)
{
getURL("http://goverment.datavideo.us");

I've searched google with nothing to point me into the right direction.

We have Joomla CMS.

Comment: I'm not very experienced with Fllash/xml, so I'll comment instead of answer:  This may be linked to content that you are grabbing from your domain and the crossdomain.xml http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html

Comment: I wonder if you're running into the XSS (cross-site scripting) restrictions built into Flash... I don't know much about the details, but it's conceivable that not having the www on the front of your URL, and linking to subdomains, causes this restriction to kick in.

See http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12541/crossdomain-file-loading-restrictions about fixing this with a crossdomain.xml config file.

Answer (score 0):

domain.com and www.domain.com are not same for an SWF movie. If your SWF is accessed from domain.com then URLs starting with www.domain.com will not work and a crossdomain policy will be needed to allow access to domain.com.

A better idea would be to set an HTACCESS file in your server root which has a permanent redirect for all traffic from domain.com to www.domain.com so that the visitor's never go to domain.com. As a side effect your page rank will also improve.